# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' while trying to import echarts in a svelte/svelt-kit project

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, svelte, sveltekit, echarts

I am trying to use Apache echarts inside a svelte/svelte-kit project for dynamic data visualization purpose.

While trying to `import * as echarts from 'echarts/core';` it throws me the following error.

```
export * from './lib/export/core.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24
```

Having in mind that this could be possibly related to ECMAScript modules syntax (export * from) in a context that does not support it.
I tried to implement some recommendations that i have got around.

First i tried to make the following changes in my `svelte.config` file  with the intention of replacing the default export of ECharts (export default echarts;) with a named export (export { echarts };). as follows:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess(
        { scss: true },
        {
            async script({ content, attributes }) {
                if (attributes.src && attributes.src.includes('node_modules/echarts')) {
                    return {
                        code: content.replace('export default echarts;', 'export { echarts };')
                    };
                }
                return { code: content };
            }
        }
    ),

    kit: {}
};

export default config;
```

However this didn't work out.

Then i went to the specific file of the echarts dependecies( `tsconfig.json` inside the node_modules)
I saw the "target":"ES3" causing an error.
However i don't know how to fix this error since i am a junior to development.
You may refer the `tsconfig.json` below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES3",

        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,

        // https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/issues/12#issuecomment-536173372
        "moduleResolution": "node",

        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": false,

        "importHelpers": true,

        "pretty": true,

        "outDir": "lib"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "extension-src/**/*.ts",
        "test/lib/myTransform/src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

I would appreciate your kind explanations in solving the problem.
Below i am attaching my `package.json` file in case you need to know the dependencies i am using and their versions.

```
{
    "name": "flight-tracker",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "npm run test:integration && npm run test:unit",
        "test:integration": "playwright test",
        "test:unit": "vitest",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.20.4",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "prettier": "^2.8.0",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.10.1",
        "sass": "^1.63.6",
        "svelte": "^4.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.6",
        "vitest": "^0.32.2"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "echarts": "^5.4.2",
        "keycloak-js": "^21.1.2",
        "ol": "^7.4.0",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^5.0.4",
        "websocket": "^1.0.34"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that `echarts` that you are trying to import an `ESM` ??

Comment: @NalinRanjan yes i am trying to import echarts into my svelte project as per the Apache Echarts documentation ```// Import the echarts core module, which provides the necessary interfaces for using echarts. import * as echarts from 'echarts/core'; // Import bar charts, all with Chart suffix import { BarChart } from 'echarts/charts'; // import rectangular coordinate system component, all suffixed with Component```

Comment: usually this error happens when as `esm` is loaded by a `commonjs` type of loader. somewhere your module/js loaders are getting mixed up. Is there a reason you have kept your target as `ES3` in your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: also ... give other import forms a try as well .. for example, `import { BarChart } from 'echarts/charts';`, and see what happens.

Comment: No the `tsconfig.json` is actually a file inside the `node_modules` of the Echarts dependencies. I have mentioned it here because i want to draw attention since this is the very file triggering the error.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed  `import * as echarts from 'echarts';` instead of  `import * as echarts from 'echarts/core';` fixes the error.
However, this is contrary to Echarts Documentation. Particularly in the [Install Echarts Via NMP](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/basics/import/#install-echarts-via-npm) section; It is stated as follows.

> There are two approaches to using ECharts as a package. The simplest approach is to make all functionality immediately available by importing from echarts. However, it is **encouraged** to **substantially decrease bundle size** by **only importing** as necessary such as `echarts/core` and `echarts/charts`.

Well, for the time being i am obliged to use the not "encouraged" way of importing all functionalities from echart - having in mind its effects on the bundle size.
However, it would be great if somebody can approach the Echarts dev team and report the specific bug reported in the above question.